# Tax price issue

Tags: magento2, tax

How do I show 20% tax at checkout page with product original price? Means we not adding extra 20% to the product price but we should show 20% including tax

Comment: what have you tried? this should be a config setting

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should solve your problem:

Navigate to **Admin > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Tax** and in the tab "Calculation Settings" set "Catalog Prices" prices to **"Include Tax"**.

> This sets whether catalog prices entered from Magento Admin include tax.

Also, in the same configuration section (**Admin > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Tax**), you will find the display setting, so you can adjust that to fit your needs.